# Need to parse output of command in python

Tags: python, command, centos7

need to capture package ,Arch ,Version , I want ot do this in python
I have atteched the image for the data

I want list od required rpm to install in centos,
Want to resolve dependancy list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3aaJ.png)

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: what did you try? where is your code? There is no special function to parse it. You will have to create own code for this. You may have to read line by line until you find second line with `===` and next read lines and split on spaces (until you get next line with `===`). Eventually you can get all text and split on `"=\n"` to get every text befween lines `===` as separated part and later work with part which have expected values.